# WPF Window Margin At Runtime not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having `WPF` windows height and width are fix. When i started the windows on the basic of user input i need to make only half portion visible of window at runtime. I am trying to set margin as below (in `Window_Loaded` method) but it is not working.

```
this.Margin = new Thickness(0, -300, 0, 0);
```

below are the window attribute properties :-

```
Height="767" Width="1032" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing" Closed="Window_Closed" WindowState="Normal" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="#FFC7C7C7" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None"
```

Can you please help how can i change windows alignment so it will show only half part to bottom of desktop.

I have attached a image, its a single window in which part 1 need to be cut and part 2 will be visible. 
[image]
I tried to change the height of the window but it cut the height from bottom. which cut part 2 instead of part 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Window .....>
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>        
          <RowDefinition/>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions/>
      <Grid Grid.Row="0" Name="gridpart1"> ... part 1 </Grid>
      <Grid Grid.Row="1"> ....part 2 </Grid>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

and from the code try to set the "Visibility" property of the grid which contains the part one to Collapsed.

```
this.gridpart1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

UPDATE : if case  you want the top part of the window blank (mean the window size will not shrink int the size) you can follow the same model and use the following statement instead

```
this.gridpart1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: its taking screen to top alignment. I want top part to be blank. window should visible on just above taskbar and top of desktop will be visible.

Comment: `this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                this.WindowStartupLocation=WindowStartupLocation.Manual;`
Above solves problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Margin` on the main `Grid` within your window instead of the window's `Margin`:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" >

mainGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, -300, 0, 0);
```

Comment: its taking screen to top alignment. I want top part to be blank. window should visible on just above taskbar and top of desktop will be visible.